# How to listen to page url change in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, components, render

I have a react component that is rendered in two different pages and I want it to have different css for each page. So I passed it a prop to switch between the css classes, but, because there is no page refresh between the 2 pages, my component doesn't change the css class, only if I manually refresh the page, my component sees the prop I passed and changes the css class.
Can anyone tell me how can I make the component rerender on page change ? even if there is no page refresh?
I tried, until now, to change the state of the component with componentDidUpdate, but it ends up rerendering on a infinite loop, and the page doesn't load anymore.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve the problem using [history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history). This will help you to track the URL changes.

if you're using a functional component you can use [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)

the second solution that comes to my mind is to use the param as the key of the component, that will force the re-render.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are using react router dom, if so I think getting the location by doing useLocation() would achieve the desired result as when the url changes this hook would cause a re-render
`const location = useLocation()`

Comment: how should I use useHistory() more exactly ?

Comment: Sorry I added a snippet of how to use it, just import from react-router-dom the useHistory as well